# MySQL not allowing remote connections from new server

Tags: mysql

I currently have one server that's connecting to a centralized MySQL server (say, 192.168.0.10). This server already allows remote connections from this IP address (say, 192.168.0.20), and in spite of my changes so far, continues to work. For this one IP address.

When I try to grant access to this same username and password from different hosts like this:

```
update db set host='192.168.0.%' where user='username';
update user set host='192.168.0.%' where user='username';
flush privileges;
```

Everything still stays the same. I can still connect from 192.168.0.20, but I also still can't connect from 192.168.0.25. I get the error message

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.0.25' is not allowed to connect to
>   this MySQL server

I can't see how this is wrong. All the documentation says it should work. I'm also not firewalling connections from 192.168.0.25. Even restarting MySQL has no effect. Other IPs on this network can connect to MySQL without any issue - even ones that were previously not allowed - and I can ping 192.168.0.10 from 192.168.0.25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify `mysql.user` table, not  only the `mysql.db`.

The proper syntax is:

```
RENAME USER 'user'@'192.168.0.10' TO 'user'@'192.168.0.%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Oops, I already had. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Or... not? I had before, but I used a hostname and wildcard instead of an IP address with wildcard. I'd changed that in the host table but not the user table. Fixing this inconsistency now allows me to connect. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have put it in with the bread-knife :)